# Date picker of bootstrap are not working

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using the following code and its not working ,I want to use bootstrap for it,what am I doing wrong ?

I try many things to add without any success....I dont have any error in the console after I add the section scripts...

```
<div class="form-group">

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />   
        <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
            </i>
        </span>
    </div>



    @section scripts {

        <script type="text/javascript">


            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
                    pickTime: false
                });
            });
        </script>

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a DatetimePicer with BS3 - no "Time". Please have a look and a working demo as follow.

```
<div class="container well">
    DatetimePicker example#1 from <a href="http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/">eonasdan</a>
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false
    });
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/4HUuJ/5/show/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to include the sources, for example

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Then just use the following script for the input with the specified id:

```
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datetimepicker4" ).datepicker();
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks But I try it and its not working ,there is additional things which I need to verify that maybe missing ?

Comment: Try adding this as well: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
You can also check out this example: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/wiki/Installation). You need these lines as initial.

```
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
</head>
```

Comment: Ok I add the bootstrap.min.css which I already have in the content folder and it still doht work ,from where I should Get the /bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js ?do I need to add it to the content folder where the bootstrap min is locketed ?

Answer (score 1):

I think, You are using date and time picker from this link : http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

and for that you need this scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

then your code will work..

Comment: I add it and it still dont working ,I use it from the following link maybe there is something else missing ?http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ I add the following links in my update post